# Частицы не и ни

Tags: не-или-ни

Прочитал ответы на подобные вопросы, но нужной мне информации не нашёл. У меня перечисление: "Ни министр, ни депутат, ни прокурор...". Мне думается, что здесь стоит *ни* потому, что слышится *ни*. Прав ли я?

Comment: Пожалуйста, сформулируйте свой вопрос четче.

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос, стараясь сделать его более конкретным,  и убрал "воду". Надеюсь, автор на меня не обидится.

Answer (score 2):

Дело не в "слышимости"; всё решает продолжение: *утверждается* далее что-то или *отрицается*, например:

> **Ни** министр, **ни** депутат, **ни** прокурор **не** прекратили тот жестокий спор.
>
> **Не** министр, **не** депутат, **не** прокурор - ослов погонщик к нам спустился с гор.

Answer (score 2):

**Ни министр, ни депутат, ни прокурор не прекратили тот жестокий спор.**

1) В безударной позиции частицы НЕ и НИ **произносятся одинаково** (как НИ), поэтому для их различения используется грамматический анализ.

2) Это повторяющийся соединительный союз ***НИ....НИ*** при  наличии отрицания у глагола (***не прекратили***).  Частица НИ усиливает уже выраженное отрицание.

3) Обратим внимание на то, что союз ***НИ...НИ*** является **аналогом союза *И...И*** в утвердительных конструкциях, сравнить: И министр, и депутат, и прокурор...

4) Повторяющийся союз *НИ...НИ* **следует отличать** от повтора отрицательной частицы *НЕ*, если в предложении имеется или подразумевается противопоставление: Не министр, не депутат, не прокурор, а (кто?)...

5) Примечание. Частицы НЕ и НИ могут различаться по ударению в местоименных конструкциях: *никог**о** не прошу – н**е**кого попросить*.